# Media Queries in LWC Not Loading

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I have a bunch of LWCs that are styled with a CSS grid. It seems like the media queries have stopped loading. I am not sure how long this may be been the case. Just recently had a BA test something again in mobile.

An example is this HTML. Both the button-forward and button-back classes have media queries on them. When l look in dev tools they are not loading and changing the row assignment.

I know these all used to work and am totally stumped about this issue. Any help would be amazing.

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="button-back">
        <c-nav-button 
            app={app} 
            style-classes={backStyle} 
            button-name={backButtonName}
            current-nav={currentPageNum} 
            disabled={backDisabled}
            custom-nav={customBackStep} 
            onpost_nav={handlePostNav}
            route="backward">
        </c-nav-button>
    </div>
    <div class="button-forward">
        <c-nav-button 
            app={app} 
            style-classes={nextStyle} 
            button-name={nextButtonName}
            current-nav={currentPageNum} 
            disabled={nextDisabled}
            custom-nav={customNextStep} 
            onpost_nav={handlePostNav}
            route="forward">
        </c-nav-button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS file:

```css
.button-back {
    grid-column: 2 / span 3;
}

.button-forward {
    grid-column: 7 / -2;
}

@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 320px)
and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .button-back,
    .button-forward {
        grid-column: 1 / -1;
    }

    .button-forward {
        grid-row: 2;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
}

@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 481px)
and (max-device-width: 1024px){
    .button-back {
        grid-column: 2 / 5;
    }
    .button-forward {
        grid-column: 7 / 10;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

One of the devs on my team noticed that if we change the formatting of the media query to:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px)
and (max-device-width: 1024px)
```

Instead of

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 481px)
and (max-device-width: 1024px)
```

All the media queries work again. But when I look at the repo they seem to have always been formatted with each `and` condition on its own line.

It is a fix, but a fix I don't understand. Hoping someone else may have experience with this.